# Constant Dns.java line 5 errors on crashlytics

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have implemented my okhttp client as follows in my app:

```
fun getOkhttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
val chuckerCollector = ChuckerCollector(
    context = MyApplication.appInstance!!,
    // Toggles visibility of the push notification
    showNotification = BuildConfig.DEBUG,
    // Allows to customize the retention period of collected data
    retentionPeriod = RetentionManager.Period.ONE_WEEK
)

// Create the Interceptor
val chuckerInterceptor = ChuckerInterceptor.Builder(MyApplication.appInstance!!)
    // The previously created Collector
    .collector(chuckerCollector)
    // The max body content length in bytes, after this responses will be truncated.
    .maxContentLength(250_000L)
    .alwaysReadResponseBody(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    .build()

val executorService: ExecutorService =
    ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 20, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, LinkedBlockingQueue())
val myDispatcher = Dispatcher(executorService)

return OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
    .addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor())
    .addInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
    .dispatcher(myDispatcher)
    .apply {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            addInterceptor(logging)
        }
    }
    .build()
}
```

Open the app for the first time everything works fine.
Put the app in background for about 30 to 40 mins and come back to the app.
Call any api and it will give -

Non-fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException Unable to resolve host "host_url":        No address associated with hostname java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName (Inet6AddressImpl.java:157) java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr (Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName (InetAddress.java:1154) okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup (Dns.java:5) okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress (RouteSelector.java:133) okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy (RouteSelector.java:20) okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next (RouteSelector.java:17) okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection (ExchangeFinder.java:196) okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection (ExchangeFinder.java) okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find (ExchangeFinder.java:47) okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp (RealCall.java:31) okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:11) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:191) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:167) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:34) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor.intercept (ChuckerInterceptor.java:9) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) com.pharmasentinel.medsii.retrofit.HeaderInterceptor.intercept (HeaderInterceptor.java:37) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp (RealCall.java:113) okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.java:51) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)

Caused by android.system.GaiException android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname) libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo (Linux.java) libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo (BlockGuardOs.java:172) java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName (Inet6AddressImpl.java:137) java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr (Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName (InetAddress.java:1154) okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup (Dns.java:5) okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress (RouteSelector.java:133) okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy (RouteSelector.java:20) okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next (RouteSelector.java:17) okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection (ExchangeFinder.java:196) okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection (ExchangeFinder.java) okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find (ExchangeFinder.java:47) okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp (RealCall.java:31) okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept (ConnectInterceptor.java:11) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept (CacheInterceptor.java:191) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept (BridgeInterceptor.java:167) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept (RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:34) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor.intercept (ChuckerInterceptor.java:9) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) com.pharmasentinel.medsii.retrofit.HeaderInterceptor.intercept (HeaderInterceptor.java:37) okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed (RealInterceptorChain.java:166) okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp (RealCall.java:113) okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run (RealCall.java:51) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)

Which i am logging from my interceptor using try catch.

Open any other app and they work fine.
Kill the app and restart resolves the problem, and sometimes switching between wifi and cellular also solves it.

Comment: `Unable to resolve host "host_url"` -- is that literally what the error has, or did you edit the error message to hide the real URL? Also, if you simplify your `OkHttpClient.Builder` configuration (e.g., remove Chucker), does the problem go away?

Comment: i am hiding the url as of now. And this was happening before adding chucker.